# How to make dynamically view to result multiple page from one database without repeat function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am still a novice on the CodeIgniter, I want to display a database to many pages dynamically. I want the view are display one by one row from the database without repeating functions.

This is my view

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <br>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">

                        <tr>
                              <th class= "htabel">Nama</th>
                              <td>Wendi Kuswiandi</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <th class= "htabel">Alamat</th>
                              <td>Geger Arum</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <th class= "htabel">No. Kontak</th>
                              <td>0888009000</td>    

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                              <th class= "htabel">Email Penulis</th>
                              <td>waranday@gmail.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

And I confused about the other model or controller code
Please help all sorry my english is still messed up.
Thank you before.

Comment: you have one view page and need to show multiple dynamic pages with different controller calls. am i right ?

Comment: i think you can use pagination for solving your problem. refer http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html?highlight=pagination

Comment: @safinchacko all of my multiple page is same of that

Comment: @noushidp There are not a pagination like display number 1, 2, 3 etc